# Would offer a tor middle relay with OpenBSD 6.0

Tags: configuration, onion-routing, openbsd

Is it possible to restrict the traffic to max 150 GB per month.

More traffic is not available to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks that you consider running a relay.
You can edit your `torrc` and tell Tor to spend less than 150 GB a month. If this limit is reached Tor goes into some kind of sleep mode and wakes up the next month.

Just add the following lines to your configuration:

```
AccountingMax 150 GBytes
AccountingRule sum
AccountingStart month 12 3:45
```

Using those lines your Tor process will sum sent and received Bytes up 150 GB and then stop running. Please make sure to add `AccountingRule sum`, because the default behavior is to look for the maximum of sent or received Bytes. If you leave out this option, your Tor relay will use rougly 300 GB.

The `AccountingStart` line tells Tor that an accounting period goes one month and starts at the 12th of the month at 3:45.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this through setting some [Accounting options](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#AccountingMax) in your torrc file.